Writing testbench for block design on Vivado
I'm working on a simple traffic lights project for my school's digital systems lab, and want to simulate the whole design using testbench before loading into hardware. I've previously done simulation for the FSM (mss_0), and everything worked as expected. Now I'm into writing the test code for the entire design, but I'm not familiar with Vivado's hdl wrapper generation. The wrapper code has too many I/O signals that I don't know where they come from or what they do! (I have the suspicion they come from the clocking wizard IP).
I just wanted to test a few signals (signals I thought were the only ones in existence). Now also arises a question about clocking generation, as I have included the clocking wizard IP, how do I manage that on simulation?
The only signas I want under test are:

start_0
reset_0
cambio_amarillo_0 (set light to yellow)
cambio_rojo_0 (set light to red)
cambio_verde_0 (set light to green)
led_verde_0 (light the green LED)
led_amarillo_0 (light the yellow LED)
led_rojo_0 (light the red LED)
estados_0 (state value of the FSM)

Here's the Block Design:

Here's the wrapper code of the block design:
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.VCOMPONENTS.ALL;
entity design_1_wrapper is
  port (
    DDR_addr : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 14 downto 0 );
    DDR_ba : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 2 downto 0 );
    DDR_cas_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_ck_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_ck_p : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_cke : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_cs_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_dm : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 3 downto 0 );
    DDR_dq : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );
    DDR_dqs_n : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 3 downto 0 );
    DDR_dqs_p : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 3 downto 0 );
    DDR_odt : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_ras_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_reset_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_we_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    FIXED_IO_ddr_vrn : inout STD_LOGIC;
    FIXED_IO_ddr_vrp : inout STD_LOGIC;
    FIXED_IO_mio : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 53 downto 0 );
    FIXED_IO_ps_clk : inout STD_LOGIC;
    FIXED_IO_ps_porb : inout STD_LOGIC;
    FIXED_IO_ps_srstb : inout STD_LOGIC;
    cambio_amarillo_0 : in STD_LOGIC;
    cambio_rojo_0 : in STD_LOGIC;
    cambio_verde_0 : in STD_LOGIC;
    estados_0 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 2 downto 0 );
    led_amarillo_0 : out STD_LOGIC;
    led_rojo_0 : out STD_LOGIC;
    led_verde_0 : out STD_LOGIC;
    reset_0 : in STD_LOGIC;
    start_0 : in STD_LOGIC
  );
end design_1_wrapper;

architecture STRUCTURE of design_1_wrapper is
  component design_1 is
  port (
    DDR_cas_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_cke : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_ck_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_ck_p : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_cs_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_reset_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_odt : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_ras_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_we_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_ba : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 2 downto 0 );
    DDR_addr : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 14 downto 0 );
    DDR_dm : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 3 downto 0 );
    DDR_dq : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );
    DDR_dqs_n : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 3 downto 0 );
    DDR_dqs_p : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 3 downto 0 );
    FIXED_IO_mio : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 53 downto 0 );
    FIXED_IO_ddr_vrn : inout STD_LOGIC;
    FIXED_IO_ddr_vrp : inout STD_LOGIC;
    FIXED_IO_ps_srstb : inout STD_LOGIC;
    FIXED_IO_ps_clk : inout STD_LOGIC;
    FIXED_IO_ps_porb : inout STD_LOGIC;
    cambio_amarillo_0 : in STD_LOGIC;
    cambio_rojo_0 : in STD_LOGIC;
    cambio_verde_0 : in STD_LOGIC;
    estados_0 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 2 downto 0 );
    led_amarillo_0 : out STD_LOGIC;
    led_rojo_0 : out STD_LOGIC;
    led_verde_0 : out STD_LOGIC;
    reset_0 : in STD_LOGIC;
    start_0 : in STD_LOGIC
  );
  end component design_1;
begin
design_1_i: component design_1
     port map (
      DDR_addr(14 downto 0) => DDR_addr(14 downto 0),
      DDR_ba(2 downto 0) => DDR_ba(2 downto 0),
      DDR_cas_n => DDR_cas_n,
      DDR_ck_n => DDR_ck_n,
      DDR_ck_p => DDR_ck_p,
      DDR_cke => DDR_cke,
      DDR_cs_n => DDR_cs_n,
      DDR_dm(3 downto 0) => DDR_dm(3 downto 0),
      DDR_dq(31 downto 0) => DDR_dq(31 downto 0),
      DDR_dqs_n(3 downto 0) => DDR_dqs_n(3 downto 0),
      DDR_dqs_p(3 downto 0) => DDR_dqs_p(3 downto 0),
      DDR_odt => DDR_odt,
      DDR_ras_n => DDR_ras_n,
      DDR_reset_n => DDR_reset_n,
      DDR_we_n => DDR_we_n,
      FIXED_IO_ddr_vrn => FIXED_IO_ddr_vrn,
      FIXED_IO_ddr_vrp => FIXED_IO_ddr_vrp,
      FIXED_IO_mio(53 downto 0) => FIXED_IO_mio(53 downto 0),
      FIXED_IO_ps_clk => FIXED_IO_ps_clk,
      FIXED_IO_ps_porb => FIXED_IO_ps_porb,
      FIXED_IO_ps_srstb => FIXED_IO_ps_srstb,
      cambio_amarillo_0 => cambio_amarillo_0,
      cambio_rojo_0 => cambio_rojo_0,
      cambio_verde_0 => cambio_verde_0,
      estados_0(2 downto 0) => estados_0(2 downto 0),
      led_amarillo_0 => led_amarillo_0,
      led_rojo_0 => led_rojo_0,
      led_verde_0 => led_verde_0,
      reset_0 => reset_0,
      start_0 => start_0
    );
end STRUCTURE;

How do I manage the IP blocks? Why all those variables get created in the wrapper? Will the testbench work if I only consider the signals I'm interested in?

Did you try it and ignore  the extraneous signals?

That's the problem with trying to do a very simple design on a very complex chip.
It appears that your design is targeting a Zynq chip of some sort. In addition to the programmable logic (PL), these chips have a hard-logic processor subsystem (PS), which includes multiple CPUs, an SDRAM controller, and many peripherals. When you generated your wrapper, Vivado included all of the I/O for the PS, even though you don't have it instantiated in your block diagram.
I'm not sure what to recommend at this point. Given that all of your modules are RTL, I think that it would be best to simply abandon the block diagram (at least for this level of design verification), and instead write your own top-level RTL module to tie everything together. This allows you to precisely define the I/O, and then you can write your test bench against that.
For testing your logic, you really don't need to simulate the clocking wizard; just have your test bench directly provide the signal that it would be generating.
